# pip - is it possible to preinstall a lib, so that any requirements.txt that is run containing that lib won't need to re-build it?

Tags: python, pip

So my scenario is that I'm trying to create a Dockerfile that I can build on my Mac for running Spacy in production. The production server contains a Nvidia GPU with CUDA. To get Spacy to use GPU, I need the lib `cupy-cuda117`. That lib won't build on my Mac because it can't find the CUDA GPU. So what I'm trying to do is create an image from the Linux server that has the CUDA GPU, that's already pre-build `cupy-cuda117` on it. I'll then use that as the parent image for Docker, as all other libs in my requirements.txt will build on my Mac.

My goal at the moment is to build that lib into the server, but I'm not sure the right path forward. Is it `sudo pip3 intall cupy-cuda117`? Or should I create a venv, and `pip3 install cupy-cuda117`? Basically my goal is later to add all the other app code and full requirements.txt, and when `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` is run by Docker, it'll download/build/install everything, but not `cupy-cuda117`, because hopefully it'll see that it's already been built.

FYI the handling of using GPU on the prod server and CPU on the dev computer i've already got sorted, it's just the building of that one package I'm stuck on. I basically just need it not to try and rebuild on my Mac. Thanks!

```
FROM "debian:bullseye-20210902-slim" as builder

# install build dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential git locales \
    && apt-get clean && rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/*_*

# Set the locale
RUN sed -i '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //g' /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen

ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8


WORKDIR "/app"

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y sudo


# Install Python 3.9 reqs
RUN sudo apt install -y  --no-install-recommends wget libxml2 libstdc++6 zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev curl libbz2-dev

# Install Python 3.9
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.1/Python-3.9.1.tgz && \
  tar -xf Python-3.9.1.tgz && \
  cd Python-3.9.1 && \
  ./configure --enable-optimizations && \
  make -j $(nproc) && \
  sudo make altinstall && \
  cd .. && \
  sudo rm -rf Python-3.9.1 && \
  sudo rm -rf Python-3.9.1.tgz


# Install CUDA
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.7.1/local_installers/cuda_11.7.1_515.65.01_linux.run && \
  sudo chmod +x cuda_11.7.1_515.65.01_linux.run && \
  sudo ./cuda_11.7.1_515.65.01_linux.run --silent --override --toolkit --samples --toolkitpath=/usr/local/cuda-11.7 --samplespath=/usr/local/cuda --no-opengl-libs && \
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.7 /usr/local/cuda && \
  sudo rm -rf cuda_11.7.1_515.65.01_linux.run

## Add NVIDIA CUDA to PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH ##
RUN echo 'case ":${PATH}:" in\n\
  *:"/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64":*)\n\
    ;;\n\
  *)\n\
  if [ -z "${PATH}" ] ; then\n\
    PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin\n\
  else\n\
    PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin:$PATH\n\
  fi\n\
esac\n\
case ":${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:" in\n\
  *:"/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64":*)\n\
    ;;\n\
  *)\n\
  if [ -z "${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}" ] ; then\n\
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64\n\
  else\n\
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH\n\
  fi\n\
esac\n\
export PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH\n\
export GLPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu\n\
export GLLINK=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu\n\
export DFLT_PATH=/usr/lib\n'\
>> ~/.bashrc

ENV PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64"
ENV GLPATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ENV GLLINK="-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ENV DFLT_PATH="/usr/lib"

RUN python3.9 -m pip install -U wheel setuptools

RUN sudo pip3.9 install torch torchvision torchaudio

RUN sudo pip3.9 install -U 'spacy[cuda117,transformers]'

# set runner ENV
ENV ENV="prod"

CMD ["bash"]
```

My local Dockerfile is this:

```
FROM myacct/myimg:latest

ENV ENV=prod

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements /code/requirements

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY ./app /code/app

ENV ENV=prod

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

Comment: Your plan -- building a base image with the cuda library installed -- seems like a good one. If you install `cupy-cuda117` into a virtual environment you would need to install the *rest* of your dependencies and your application into the same virtual environment. For a container image like this it's probably easier just to `pip install` things globally.

Comment: @larsks Ok, so skip venv all together? I guess that makes a lot of sense, it's a Docker image specifically to run this app in production, so cross project versioning is not really going to be an issue here as it would be in other scenarios. Ok. So i'll kill the venv, sudo install the python lib that requires CUDA, and trying to start from there as my parent image.

Comment: The "global install within container" is a perfectly good approach, go for it. If you want it to be similar to what developers use, consider using `pip3 install -r early_requirements.txt`, later followed by using the usual requirements.txt. That is, you can have a series of files which build up your venv.

Comment: @J_H Ok, i've got a dockerfile and image that i've built on a AWS instance with CUDA. When I pull that from dockerhub on my laptop and try to use it as a base image, I get a `pip3: not found` error. I have a feeling I'm just missing something small in my Dockerfile. Any idea what it could be? I've edited my post to include it, if not, I can open a new question. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that symptom sounds like an easy one, given that python ships standard with pip. Here's the most bullet proof invocation: `python -m pip install ...`, and use `$ which python` to tell which one you're getting, and `$ python -m site` to see where libs are imported from. Alternate invocations: `pip3` or `pip`. (When python2 was a thing the difference used to matter, but less so these days.) Remember that `sudo ...` gives you a different `$PATH` env var, so `sudo which python` might yield a different answer.